# Laravel cache configuration about cache stores

Tags: laravel, caching

What does "array" mean in this section?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWjYf.png)

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Stores
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
| well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
| same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
|
| Supported drivers: "apc", "array", "database", "file",
|            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "null"
|
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `array` cache driver, the cache will be stored in a PHP array, this feature is supposed to be used for testing purposes and for storing cache data for a single browser request, you can find more in the Laravel official docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#configuration

To debug using this method you can do something like this:
Put a key - value in cache:

```
Cache::put('key', 'value', 600);
```

Where 600 is the number of seconds the cache will last.

Retrieve it from cache

```
$value = Cache::get('key');
```

Comment: I had read the Docs and didn't figure out how it works. I wanna ask what driver is that PHP array operated on?

Comment: It literally is a non-persistent PHP array that you can use to store stuff during testing and/or store cached value during a single browser request, since you can actually use more cache driver in your application using the `Cache` facade. For example `Cache::store('redis')->put('key','value',600)` will store a value for 10 minutes in redis while `Cache::store('array')->put('key','value,600)` will store a value from 10 minutes in a PHP array used as cache